# Replicating Verity Collections across multiple Coldfusion servers

Tags: coldfusion

I have three load-balanced Coldfusion servers running my application.  Any time I create or index a Verity Collection, the changes are only reflected on the server that handled the request.  Is there a way to synchronize these changes to all my Coldfusion servers?

Answer (score 1):

The ColdFusion server OEM license for Verity K2 server limits usage of Verity to a single host.  If you have multiple server instances running on the same machine, then you run a single Verity K2 server instance and each local instance will work with it.  An update to a Verity collection will be immediately visible to all CF instances on that machine.

If you have another host with ColdFusion, then you functionally connect it to the same Verity K2 server on the other machine, and it would break the EULA if you did.

That said, I know how to re-configure Verity K2 to work with ColdFusion servers across multiple hosts (which would break the EULA and get me in trouble).  Unfortunately, I can't tell you.

Earlier versions of ColdFusion MX (i.e. MX 6.0/6.1) were able to connect multiple ColdFusion servers on different hosts to single K2 server, but that went away in ColdFusion 7 and later.

Finally, for multiple CF instances on a single host, changes to the Verity collections *will* be reflected immediately in other CF instances on that host.  This is because there is a single Verity K2 server with all the collections in memory, and each ColdFusion server speaks to the K2 server over TCP in a client-server relationship.